# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema al momento de ordenar una lista de x nombres introducidos en un arreglo tipo string utilizando burbuja en c++?

Tags: c++, string, ordenamiento

Buen día!

Tengo un problema a la hora de compilar mi código.
Estoy intentando hacer un ordenamiento de datos tipo string, los cuales tratan de
"x" cantidad de nombres los cuales deben de ser ordenados mediante método de la burbuja.
El detalle es que:
En la pantalla del compilador me sale:

"
|error: cannot convert 'std::__cxx11::string' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string'} to 'const char*'|"

No sé a qué se deberá.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int size=0,i,j;
    string temp[30];
    cout<<"----------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"Introduzca la cantidad de nombres a ordenar: "<<endl;
    cin>>size;
    string nombres[size];
    while(i<size)
    {
        cout<<"Nombre # ["<<i+1<<"]: ";
        cin>>nombres[i];
        i++;
    }
    cout<<"----------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"Los nombres ingresados son: "<<endl;
    for (i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        cout<<nombres[i]<<endl;
    }
     cout<<"----------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        for(j=i;j<size;j++)
            {
                if(strcmp(nombres[i],nombres[j])<0)
                {
                    strcpy(temp,nombres[i]);
                    strcpy(nombres[i],nombres[j]);
                    strcpy(nombres[j],temp);

                }
            }
}
```

Comment: Sería muy útil que indicases en **qué** línea sucede el error que describes.

Answer (score 2):

Voy a traducir el mensaje de error:

> cannot convert 'std::__cxx11::string' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string'} to 'const char*'

> no se puede convertir 'std::__cxx11::string' {tcc<sup>1</sup> 'std::__cxx11::basic_string'} a 'const char*'

En algún punto de tu código estás usando una cadena de caracteres (`std::string` que es un alias de `std::basic_string`) en el lugar en que se esperaba un puntero constante a caracteres (`const char *`).

Y eso sucede al usar la función [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp), cuya firma es:

> ```
> int strcmp( const char *lhs, const char *rhs );
> ```

A la cuál estás llamando con dos parámetros de tipo `std::string`:

```
    string nombres[size];

    ...
    ...
    ...

               if(strcmp(nombres[i],nombres[j])<0)
//                       ^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^
//                           |          |
// Ambos son 'std::string', la función espera 'const char *'
```

Dicho esto: todo tu código está mal, y no sólo por el error que has descrito.

1. **C no es C++**: Los lenguajes C y C++ no son el mismo, existe una retrocompatibilidad de C++ hacia C que permite compilar la mayoría del código C en compiladores C++ pero para ello hay que seguir una serie de pautas que no has seguido.

   - Las cabeceras `<string.h>` y `<stdlib.h>` son del lenguaje C y no deben ser usadas en código C++, existe una versión adaptada a C++ de ambas cabeceras cuyo nombre es `<cstring>` y `<cstdlib>` respectivamente. Deberías usar esas cabeceras si realmente necesitas funcionalidades contenidas en las mismas (que por cierto, no es tu caso).
2. **Una cadena de C no es una cadena de C++**: C no es un lenguaje completamente orientado a objetos, por ello no dispone de un objeto de cadena de caracteres. En C las cadenas de caracteres son punteros a carácter (`char *`) y a través de `<string.h>` se ponen a disposición del programador una colección de funciones para trabajar con ese concepto de datos. Pero en C++ se dispone de un objeto que gestiona cadenas de caracteres (`std::string`) que tiene funciones integradas en el propio objeto.
3. **Estás usando formaciones de tamaño variable**: Este es un error tan común que hay decenas de preguntas/respuestas tratando el tema, así que en lugar de darte detalles te facilitaré [una búsqueda con hilos tratando el tema](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+vla).

Sabiendo eso, programando enteramente en C++, tu código podría parecerse a:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    // Se aconseja que cláusula 'using' esté en el ámbito más pequeño posible
    using namespace std;

    // Creamos un tipo de dato que almacene una cantidad arbitraria de cadenas
    using lista_cadenas = vector<string>;
    lista_cadenas nombres;

    /* No necesitas repetir llamadas a cout, todas las llamadas a cout seguidas
    pueden juntarse en una sola llamada */
    cout <<"----------------------------------------------\n"
            "Introduzca la cantidad de nombres a ordenar:\n";

    /* Declara las variables cerca del lugar en que las uses, eso hace que el
    código sea más fácil de comprender */
    int size;
    cin >> size;

    /* Por convención se usan bucles 'for' cuando se conoce la cantidad de
    iteraciones y bucles 'while' cuando no se conocen */
    for (int indice = 0; indice != size; ++indice)
    {
        string nombre;
        cin >> nombre;
        nombres.push_back(nombre);
    }

    cout << "----------------------------------------------\n"
        "Los nombres ingresados son: \n";
    /* Los bucles for de rango permiten iterar colecciones de datos de manera
    más sencilla y legible */
    for (const auto &nombre : nombres)
    {
        cout << nombre << endl;
    }

    cout << "----------------------------------------------\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = i; j < size; ++j)
        {
            if (nombres[i].compare(nombres[j]) < 0)
            //            ^
            //            |
            // Función compare de 'std::string', no 'strcmp' de <string.h>
            {
                /* Operador de igualación '=' de 'std::string'
                no 'strcpy' de <string.h> */
                string temp = nombres[i];
                nombres[i] = nombres[j];
                nombres[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    // La función 'main' debe devolver un valor.
    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVXNbhs3ED4vn2LqAl07ceycepBsXVIEKJq2AXoK0jQYcccSVS655Y8Kp/XD@NhjkUfQg7kzXK6kOKe2Kyx2d/74zfcNKT0Mz7RFt3p4@NI4bXNHcGV8TIGwX6iDjS3GrY4tW9LJh4VSxiXo0bjTM/WHai4v4ScC1N5F2iD8lgm03d3nmC1CmyNXaYFi2v0F5IAs7O77pUke@t19hIE4Yfe3h8FHs7SkmpIBDnuKA2qCmLq5Ksu8EIw@QnaQzOCBQXXIhWRJtD0HO2IngkaXTIcdYOCVAgaDEqyxI4dxWsKamPB9NcI1jP1Njc9V82mA8/0yUCxYnsAPHhxpiiaxK9BAyQSwFnvs2MAQfE7nkLx8Wbk/dUGkVWaIDGbIxAvAJruEIZKQJD1Ez/TVLHhyqZqSdnV18uxfXT@7EwV8Nc3Jty4F3@UPmuseccTE1NYYmw/SbJhxWm30G@JxCVia2AqTLFIETUELpxZsXmEQ0KKCBOVI8ZwF97AW@cRMluHvPnZm5blxHJW/2d1rY4suvh8CuY5CaVTGK5oPxApo42CxqF8FzmsfON5tyWmz@@i4HC@IDpZZC672xocWdEbXyVIS6jU96peXSBRQG@845Xaf@/vaWNpnu6MCrgDj2nAq6IzrDFe9hufz6f2L6xElPH06Ws5Uw5ujGaepMswdTS0dDJX8iyHH9fsl6l9PR8sZO@/UXnf4D8Kz6K/8fnIZ6oof2LEpejeDIrKQKkGVBOmRJQl8QvCepNAzVQ4KX0K8JV1pq5uvvPTo2K@aomsUaXhwmVhLK9nTB/LkkEiAmTftVyMqmE3wKmFTu9XNbzwZ9n9zIeNz0K9KB1cH0ery@5gNx5g5Pw4xG44pQY25gapSfGveXcgAY6C9afPujNOeS7icW0fXL5@b/qyml7mOdK0mxLZ8@M1m4wy15zKSbAm6H1o4nNEX64WUKMBEzR9ZNha56GhWGS2Oddvr9rOaJWcqO9w@KluEa/ZDnKgfmJVD4/OaPn0fOTePnBtxSoFivlPlvhvP9VcIN1PzrfyxCIylELD1dsunAh/4W7Q@XKgmUMrBsXrq7uHha/UaE/@iehnkIFYvvFPfUdLrPKg36nu8lVFF9Q8)</kbd>.

---

###### <sup>1</sup>También Conocido Como.